# disable file protocol in windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, registry

- Our client provides remote browsers for testing purposes.
- My job is to secure system so user cannot get access to client's code ( present in 'D' drive).
- I have disabled access through my computer ([link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8035/how-to-restrict-access-to-drive-in-my-computer-on-windows/)).
- But I am still able to access through file protocol in browser.
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8RkW.png)

System:

- Microsoft windows server 2003

I have tried:

- https://superuser.com/questions/843945/chrome-disable-file-protocol
  . 'file' is disabled in URLProtocol view still I can access drives from browser

How should I disable it ?

Is there any alternative way to achieve system lockdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome group policy to disable file protocol in it. Please refer to [this doc](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en) about how to use Group Policy to configure policies for Chrome.

After you have installed and configured Chrome policy templates, you can:

1. Set [Allow invocation of file selection dialogs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=AllowFileSelectionDialogs) to **Disabled**
2. Set [Block access to a list of URLs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=URLBlacklist) to **Enabled** and add **file://*** to the [url list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrRt4.png)
3. Run `gpupdate /force` in cmd to update the group policy

Then the file protocol can't be used in Chrome, the result is like this:

[image]